# How to declare data structures on base objects, so they remain independent in each extended object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Example:

```js
var Person = {
   name : '',
   collection  : new Array(),
   addToCollection : function(x)
   {
     this.collection.push(x);
   },
   printCollection: function() {
       console.log(this.collection);
   }
};


var skywalker = Object.create(Person);
skywalker.name = 'Anakin Skywalker';
skywalker.addToCollection(1);
skywalker.printCollection();   // prinnts [1]


var skywalker2 = Object.create(Person);
skywalker2.name = 'Anakin Skywalker 2';
skywalker.addToCollection(2);
skywalker2.printCollection();   // prints [1, 2]
```

I would like to achieve situation where skywalker2.printCollection();  prints [2]. I want the base object Person to be concerned with collection, and expose operations such as addToCollection(x).

Comment: Obvious mistake: why skywalker.addToCollection(2); try to add it's own object skywalker2.addToCollection(2);

Comment: Then you have to add a property called `collection` to the instantiated object itself just after instantiating it by `Object.create(Person)` and share only the functions to set and to get it (`addToCollection` and `setToCollection`) in the prototype (the `Person` object in this case)

Comment: @AliTorabi  thanks for pointing it out, this does not change the result however
@Redu In my question I stated `I want the base object Person to be concerned with collection`. By this I mean, I don't want to be adding this collection to each instantiated object. Isn't there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do like this;

```js
var Person = {
   name : '',
   addToCollection : function(x)
   {
     this.collection.push(x);
   },
   printCollection: function() {
       console.log(this.collection);
   }
};
var sw1 = Object.create(Person),
    sw2 = Object.create(Person);

sw1.collection = new Array();
sw2.collection = new Array();
sw1.addToCollection(1);
sw2.addToCollection(2);

sw1.printCollection(); // <- 1
sw2.printCollection(); // <- 2
```

Well as per the comment of the OP a little info on Object creation in JS. Object.create() will let you define the prototype of an object and anything in the prototype are shared among the instantiated objects. So in this case the collection array is shared. If you don't want the `collection` to be shared you just have to create it within the instantiated object as i have shown in the previous snippet. However as i understand you don't want that. OK then there is one more way to achieve this. We can have the `collection` array under a function as a private property and access it by a closure through our prototype methods. Then we will achieve what we wanted. Just like this;

```js
function collectionInClosure(){
  var collection = [],
   getCollection = function(){return collection},
   setCollection = function(v) {collection.push(v)};
  return {
           printCollection: function() {console.log(getCollection())},
           addToCollection: setCollection
         };
}

var sw1 = Object.create(collectionInClosure());
    sw2 = Object.create(collectionInClosure());

sw1.addToCollection(1);
sw2.addToCollection(2);

sw1.printCollection(); // <- 1
sw2.printCollection(); // <- 2
```

Comment: In my question I stated `I want the base object Person to be concerned with collection`. By this I mean, I don't want to be adding this collection to each instantiated object. Isn't there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @Tomasz Szawara Normally it's best to keep the properties that you don't want to share in the instantiated object but since you don't want that here is a way of achieving your target. Please see the second snippet and my explanation added to my answer. Both `sw1` and `sw2` objects are totally empty now.

Comment: Yes, and your extended answer is more relevant to my original question, since I only asked for the collection to be handled in base class and separately for each instantiated object. What I really wanted to have was a behaviour where all properties are public, but at the same time separate for each instance, for which my answer was suited. I failed in describing it accurately in my question though.

Answer (score 0):

Its very common practice, and a big convenience to be able to abstract some properties in base classes, so that we wouldn't need to care about them when instantiating or extending objects. Other classically object oriented languages like Java do that for us, and its generally considered a more intuitive behaviour for developers to understand.

Solution to this particular problem can be achieved in two ways:

**1) with ES6** :

```js
class Animal { 
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.collection = [];
  }
  addToCollection(x) {
    this.collection.push(x);
  }
  printCollection() {
    console.log(this.collection);
  }
}

var dog = new Animal();
dog.addToCollection(1);
dog.printCollection();    // prints 1

var dog2 = new Animal();
dog2.addToCollection(2);
dog2.printCollection();   // prints 2
```

Since not all browsers support ES6 (most browsers have ES6 switched off by default), use Babel or similar polyfill to be able to use above syntax.

Babel will use ES5 to emulate ES6 syntax with javascript similar to :

```js
"use strict";

var _createClass = function() {
  function defineProperties(target, props) {
    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
      var descriptor = props[i];
      descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
      descriptor.configurable = true;
      if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true;
      Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
    }
  }

  return function(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
    if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
    if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
    return Constructor;
  };
}();

var Animal = function() {
  function Animal(name) {
    // ..  some Babel Class checks here

    this.name = name;
    this.collection = [];
  }

  _createClass(Animal, [{
    key: "addToCollection",
    value: function addToCollection(x) {
      this.collection.push(x);
    }
  }, {
    key: "printCollection",
    value: function printCollection() {
      console.log(this.collection);
    }
  }]);

  return Animal;
}();

var dog = new Animal();
dog.addToCollection(1);
dog.printCollection();  // prints 1

var dog2 = new Animal();
dog2.addToCollection(2);
dog2.printCollection();    // prints 2
```

**2) Another way is to use ES5 syntax inspired by Babel approach:**

```js
var Person = function() {

    function Person(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.collection = [];  
        this.addToCollection = function (x) {
            this.collection.push(x);
        } 
        this.printCollection = function () {
           console.log(this.collection);
        }
    };
    return Person;
}();

var p1 = new Person();
p1.addToCollection(1);
p1.printCollection();    // prints 1

var p2 = new Person();
p2.addToCollection(2);
p2.printCollection();   // prints 2
```

By wrapping constructor Person in immediately executed function, we ensure that a new constructor is created each time somebody instantiates Person class;